# AWS post deploy directory permission change

Tags: amazon-web-services, cakephp, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am deploying to Elastic Beanstalk with Deploybot. I need to change directory permissions for /app/tmp after deployment. The tmp directory in my cake 2 installation becomes unwritable and so forces an error.

Can anyone tell me how to do this (bearing in mind im using Deplybot and not the EB CLI)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use a [Container Command](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#linux-container-commands) to `chmod` the directory appropriately. Something like this should work:

**.ebextensions/01-chmod.config**

```
container_commands:
  chmod-tmp:
    command: "chmod 777 /app/tmp"
```

Comment: found out that when cakephp is in debug mode 0 it doesnt create tmp directory and contents. Im running these container commands but it doesnt work.

Comment: container_commands:
01_chmodmkd:
command: "sudo mkdir -p 
/var/app/current/app/tmp/{cache/{persistent,views,models},logs,sessions}"

leader_only: true

02_chmodmkd2:

command: "sudo chown -R webapp:webapp /var/app/current/app/tmp/"

leader_only: true

Answer (score 0):

Right.... couldn't get the container commands to do what I wanted so came at it from the other direction.

Put .gitignore files in all the tmp folders and set the content to:

*

!.gitignore

This ignored all the files but kept the folders.